# Difference between になる / である / の

Tags: grammar, particle-の, copula

アリバイがない限り、犯人 **になる** 可能性がある。

アリバイがない限り、犯人 **である** 可能性がある。

アリバイがない限り、犯人 **の** 可能性がある。

Which sentences are correct / awkward / wrong? Why is there a difference, if any?

Comment: What are these sentences intended to mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) アリバイがない限{かぎ}り、犯人{はんにん} **になる** 可能性{かのうせい}がある。
>
> 2) アリバイがない限り、犯人 **である** 可能性がある。
>
> 3)アリバイがない限り、犯人 **の** 可能性がある。

This might depend on how you define "correct" here, but I am going to say that all three are correct.

You should, however, expect to see/hear sentence #1 by far the **least often** out of the three.  This is partly because of the slightly ambiguous meaning of  「犯人になる」, which could be taken to mean "***to become a criminal of one's own volition***".  Here, the phrase 「アリバイがない限り」("unless one has an alibi") is barely saving it from being taken that way.

To me, sentences #2 and #3 would almost equally be "correct" and common.  #2 would often sound more declarative than #3.  「の」 is such an almighty particle, which makes things easier to say but because of its versatility, it can make phrases using it sound less formal and more conversational.

Comment: 「犯人になる」というのは "own volition" 以外にも「犯人にされる（仕立て上げられる）」という意味の可能性もあると思いますがいかがでしょう。